# What is the cause of FluentValidation Method Not Found exception?

Tags: exception, fluentvalidation, api-gateway

I've got a Domain Driven Design solution and for some reason, I'm getting this exception at **RunTime** when the API call is made through **GateWay**:

```
One or more errors occurred. (Method not found: 'Void FluentValidation.AbstractValidator`1.When(System.Func`2<!0,Boolean>, System.Action)'.)
```

The error occurs as below:
[image]

I have solution like this:

[image]

The main 4 project I'm focusing on right now are:

1. Core.Model
2. Account.Api
3. Service.Api.Gateway
4. Web.ClientSite

`Web.ClientSite` makes request to `Service.Api.Gateway` which then calls `Account.Api`.
Note that `Core.Model` is referenced **everywhere**

**VERY IMPORTANT: If I remove the reference of FluentValidation from `Core.Model`, the exception disappears.**

I'm hoping these information is enough. Why do you think I'm getting this exception and how can I eliminate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like some of libs (ocelot) are incompatible with new changes in FluentValidation 8.1.2. Try to downgrade to FluentValidation before 8.1.2. Hope it helps

Comment: Thankyou!!! Your diagnose is 100% correct. However, none of the FluentValidation v8.*.* version did work with both Ocelot version 12 and 13. The only version of FluentValidation I managed to work is 7.6.105 (possibly earlier versions will work too but I used the latest I could make it work)

Comment: I was getting the same error for 10.1.0 and downgrading to 9.5.4 worked.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar exception:

> System.MissingMethodException : Method not found:
> 'FluentValidation.AssemblyScanner
> FluentValidation.AssemblyScanner.FindValidatorsInAssembly(System.Reflection.Assembly)'

In my case I needed to upgrade the ediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection and MediatR.Extensions.FluentValidation.AspNetCore packages as well to fix the issue.